# Fading an Image UI with pressing a key in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to fade an image if I press down key "A", I found a code here, in stackoverflow and tried to overwrite it to work as I want, but it still doesn't fade out my image.

```
public float FadeRate;
private Image image;
private float targetAlpha;

void Start()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        image = GetComponent<Image>();
        Material instantiatedMaterial = Instantiate<Material>(image.material);
        image.material = instantiatedMaterial;
        targetAlpha = image.color.a;

        StartCoroutine(FadeIn());
    }
}

IEnumerator FadeIn()
{
    targetAlpha = 1.0f;
    Color curColor = image.color;
    while (Mathf.Abs(curColor.a - targetAlpha) > 0.0001f)
    {
        Debug.Log(image.material.color.a);
        curColor.a = Mathf.Lerp(curColor.a, targetAlpha, FadeRate * Time.deltaTime);
        image.color = curColor;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just create a new animation instead of just flat out programming it, and then play that animation when the a key is pressed?

Comment: @CoderTang yesn't .. to use an Animator/Animation for this simple thing would be quite overkill performance wise. And most of the time Coroutines (for such simple usecase) are just 
way easier to maintain and control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first of all you have your check which button is pressed in the wrong method. Your start method should look like this:

```
void Start()
{
    image = GetComponent<Image>();
    Material instantiatedMaterial = Instantiate<Material>(image.material);
    image.material = instantiatedMaterial;
    targetAlpha = image.color.a;
}
```

Your if statement has to go into your update method. The start method only runs once after the object is initalized. Your update method runs every frame. You want to check every frame if the `A` key was pressed.

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        StartCoroutine(FadeIn());
    }
}
```

Your coroutine actually looks fine. It is doing what it should do: Fade your image **in** and **not out**. You can easily see that by looking at its name. It is called `FadeIn`. Your image is fading **in** because its `targetAlpha` is set to `1f`. This has to be changed to zero. I also renamed your method accordingly.

```
IEnumerator FadeOut()
{
    targetAlpha = 0f;
    Color curColor = image.color;
    while (Mathf.Abs(curColor.a - targetAlpha) > 0.0001f)
    {
        Debug.Log(image.material.color.a);
        curColor.a = Mathf.Lerp(curColor.a, targetAlpha, FadeRate * Time.deltaTime);
        image.color = curColor;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked!

Answer (score 0):

Just as an addition to [Daniel M's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69067610/7111561).

You can actually make `Start` itself to be a Coroutine in which case you actually could do

```
private IEnumerator Start()
{
    var image = GetComponent<Image>();
    var startAlpha = image.color.a;
    var targetAlpha = 1.0f;
    var curColor = image.color;

    yield return new WaitUntil(() => Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A));    
    
    while (!Mathf.Abs(curColor.a -  targetAlpha) > 0.0001f)
    {
        Debug.Log(image.material.color.a);
        curColor.a = Mathf.Lerp(curColor.a, targetAlpha, FadeRate * Time.deltaTime);
        image.color = curColor;

        yield return null;
    }

    // In order to end with clean values
    curColor.a = targetAlpha;
    image.color = curColor;
}
```

Note though that your Lerp will always start pretty fast and get slower and slower and probably never really reach the target alpha.

If you want to rather fade in a fixed time you could use

```
[SerializeField] private float duration = 2f;
```

and then

```
for(var factor = 0f; factor < 1; factor += Time.deltaTime / duration)
{
    // Optionally add ease-in and -out
    factor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, factor);

    curColor.a = Mathf.Lerp(startAlpha, targetAlpha, factor);
    image.color = curColor;

    yield return null;
}

// In order to end with clean values
curColor.a = targetAlpha;
image.color = curColor;
```

And then if you want total control of the blend curve you could also use an

```
[SerializeField] private AnimationCurve _fadeCurve;
```

configure it according to your needs in the Inspector and do

```
for(var factor = 0f; factor < 1; factor += Time.deltaTime / duration)
{
    
    factor = _fadeCurve.Evaluate(factor);

    curColor.a = Mathf.Lerp(startAlpha, targetAlpha, factor);
    image.color = curColor;

    yield return null;
}

// In order to end with clean values
curColor.a = targetAlpha;
image.color = curColor;
```

Comment: Thank you, interesting view!